# SharePoint online errors in console

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am opening SharePoint online. There is no issue there but when I open the console , I see the following errors and please note that the page is empty , there is no spfx or any other app added.

1. sposuitenav.js:1 GET https://_api/sphomeservice/context?$expand=Token,Payload net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

[image: error]

1. There is no paired service worker qos start event for this end event:
2. DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

[image: errors]

Comment: How do you create an empty page? It could be the cause. The 1st screenshot indicate the page is requesting a wrong URL (missing hostname). It should be the cause of 400 bad request error in 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Empty page is created by SharePoint online menu "Add page". 
Yes this is what I want to know how and where request is made to that URL

Comment: Normally "add page" will add a new page with existing layout (with top bar and left navigation). Your "empty page" still consist layout or it is really "blank"?

Comment: Thank you, There isn't any custom layout or anything in the navigation.

Comment: As long as I've worked with SharePoint, on premises and online, there have always been errors in the console. Unless you encounter a problem with SharePoint funcitonality in the user interface, why do you care about console errors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no issue so far but I want to know why I am getting those errors. Is it something alarming ...